# Fedora 3200x1800 resolution to small - can't see anything

Tags: kde, graphics, resolution, fedora

I bought the a new notebook ([Dell M3800](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-m3800-workstation/pd#TechSpec)) and installed Fedora 20 with KDE for the first time on it (actually my first Linux system ever). My problem is now, that my resolution is tooo big.. I can't see anything. And I can't even select a lower one, which should fit (**16:9**). So a friend of mine changed somehow manually the resolution to **1920x1080**, but somehow it doesn't looks like it's perfectly high resolution. He created somehow a file and a script (because when you run that file it takes effect, but after a restart it's on the QHD+ resolution again).

Anybody knows why the resolution doesn't looks like that good. Maybe somebody has a cleaner solution for me?

Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192    
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3200x1800     59.98 +
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
   1920x1080     59.96* 
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Is the native resolution of your laptop 3200x1800?

Comment: You don't really want to lower the display resolution. Instead, you want to make the fonts, etc. bigger. That results in a very crisp, fully readable display. Making the resolution lower results in a readable, but blurry display.

Comment: @derobert Yes, but what about all of my tools like browsers.. they are still small. I mean yes, i could zoom in, but is this the best solution to do it like that?

Comment: @DarioCalovic Ideally, your browser would do that automatically. Now, having said that, AFAIK HiDPI support on Linux isn't fully there yet...

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the mode on the command line with [`xrandr`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html).  Use a resolution that divides evenly into your laptop's native resolution so that it will still look crisp.  Something like 1600x900 should be a good fit for you. Unfortunately this resolution isn't available by default based on the output of `xrandr`.  Therefore you need to manually add it.  First generate the proper modeline using [`cvt`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/cvt.1.html):

```
cvt -r 1600 900 60
# 1600x900 59.82 Hz (CVT 1.44M9-R) hsync: 55.40 kHz; pclk: 97.50 MHz
Modeline "1600x900R"   97.50  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 903 908 926 +hsync -vsync
```

Take the output and add it to your mode list with `xrandr`:

```
xrandr --newmode 1600x900 97.50  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 903 908 926 +hsync -vsync
```

Now attach the new mode to the `eDP1` output:

```
xrandr --addmode eDP1 1600x900
```

Usually this command also causes the mode to be active at the same time.  If it doesn't, you need to specify it manually:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1600x900
```

Comment: I updated my answer.. i run the xrandr. and as you can see the resolution are strange, because if i choose one of them it looks weird(black sidebars).

Comment: @DarioCalovic, thanks.  I've updated this answer.  The `cvt` command only prints a modeline (it doesn't no anything behind the scenes.  I included it just to illustrate where the numbers in the first `xrandr` command come from.